# PhpStorm debugger: How to ignore webpack dev server served script (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, webpack, phpstorm, webstorm

I've setup PhpStorm to use the JavaScript debugger. When I run `yarn hot`, the exception are properly caught.

Unfortunately, it's also catching exceptions in `node_modules` and I would like to avoid that.

[image: This code is not written by me. Still, an exception is caught when "Toggle break on exception" is activated]

I've tried to add different things in the `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Stepping -> Do not step into scripts`:

```
webpack:///./node_modules/module/v-table/dist/v-table.common.js
webpack:////./node_modules/module/v-table/dist/v-table.common.js
v-table.common.js
./node_modules/module/v-table/dist/v-table.common.js
/node_modules/module/v-table/dist/v-table.common.js
./node_modules/module/v-table/dist/*
*
```

I've also tried to blackbox these scripts in Chrome.
Nothing appears to work.

My question here is more, is it even possible to have a working JavaScript debugger with PhpStorm and JavaScript? Is one of you using it?

Comment: Try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/skipped-paths.html

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, and seems to be only available for PHP. Does something exist to just say "i've seen this exception breakpoint, don't alert me again on this one"?

Comment: Not sure. I think this is possible in visual studio code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is currently no way to filter out exception breakpoints; please vote for [WEB-30378](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30378) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Thanks for your answer!